# How do I create a route on Azure to pass data from my Azure virtual network to a network attached to my corporate network?

Tags: powershell, azure, networking, routes

I have recently setup an Azure virtual network (10.10.10.0/24) and successfully connected it with a site-site VPN to our corporate network (192.168.150.0/24) using  VPN connection configured in RRAS on Windows Server 2012. We have another network (192.168.251.0/24) we access through a gateway (192.168.150.254) on our local network, but I can't access this from Azure... I've tried creating routes on VMs on Azure and also via powershell using Set-AzureRoute but I still can't access this network... Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the second network as a second local network on the VPN Gateway.